# Results from the Python interpreter's TFLite and Android's are very different

Tags: android, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I'm newbie in Android TFLite.
I converted [insightface(pytorch)](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/tree/master/recognition/arcface_torch) to TFLite, and I want to inference this model in Android.

This is very beginning part of my conversion(FP16).

[begin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snFPB.png)

And this is last part.

[end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ny5O.png)

The preprocessing of the bitmap was done exactly the same as the preprocessing for torch and tflite.
Since the preprocessing is the same, also image is same, the value of tensorbuffer is the same as shown in the figure(Different order due to axis).

The output is a float array in the shape of [1, 512], but it's a bit long, so I just put the first part in front of it.

[PC results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FKGv.png)

[Android results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5ozk.png)

But when I do a forward on Android TFLite, the range of values is completely different and I can't figure out why.

How can I handle this?

Code Snippets

```kotlin
private val fvtfImageProcessor by lazy {
    ImageProcessor.Builder()
        .add(NormalizeOp(0f, 255f))
        .add(NormalizeOp(0.5f, 0.5f))
        .build()
}
```

```kotlin
class FaceVericiationHelper(private val tflite: Interpreter){
    private val feature = arrayOf(FloatArray(512))

    fun predict(image: TensorImage): Pair<String, Float> {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        tflite.run(image.buffer, feature)
        val end_forward = System.currentTimeMillis()

        return Pair<String, Float>("as", 1f)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
val fv_tfImageBuffer = TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32)
var am_ : AssetManager = this.assets
val input_ = BufferedInputStream(am_.open("test.png"))
val alignedBitmapBuffer = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input_)
val fv_tfImage = fvtfImageProcessor.process(fv_tfImageBuffer.apply { load(alignedBitmapBuffer) })
val f = face_verificator.predict(fv_tfImage)
```

I've tried transforming the model multiple times, but the same result keeps repeating.

- PyTorch -> ONNX

```py
## PyTorch to ONNX
img_size = (112, 112)
batch_size = 1
onnx_model_path = '../weights/model_24.onnx'

model = get_model('r100', fp16=False, use_cbam=False)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('../weights/model_24.pt'))
model.eval()

sample_input = torch.rand((batch_size, 3, *img_size))

y = model(sample_input)

torch.onnx.export(
    model,
    sample_input, 
    onnx_model_path,
    verbose=False,
    input_names=['input'],
    output_names=['output'],
    opset_version=12
)
```

- ONNX -> TFLite
  I use this repository [onnx2tflite](https://github.com/MPolaris/onnx2tflite)

Comment: Hi dudskrk. Why are you adding 2 Normalization operators?

Comment: @Farmaker Hi, because of this, https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/blob/30295de48907e04077d6d22a9a8f580b525822ce/recognition/arcface_torch/inference.py#L21

Comment: Are you 100% sure that 'img.div_(255).sub_(0.5).div_(0.5)' is equal to 2 Normalize ops that you are using above? Because I am not. For this specific one probably you have to create your own buffer where you have the control like https://github.com/farmaker47/Segmentation_and_Style_Transfer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/soloupis/sample/ocr_keras/utils/ImageUtils.kt#L156-L186 where you can change the block of code where it is creating the values for the pixels.

Comment: Also based on the documentation for TensorFlow Support library that contains the ImageProcessor, it expects an image in the format of (h,w,3) or (1,h,w,3) and pytorch model uses (1,3,h,w). Probably this is a source of mistake also. You can manipulate though the above code for custom bytebuffer creation to have your values at positions 2,3 instead of 1,2 like https://github.com/farmaker47/Portrait_creator/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/soloupis/sample/photos_with_depth/utils/ImageUtils.kt#L190-L229

Comment: @Farmaker you mean that fv_Image.tensorBuffer is not exactly same as python TF tensor and preprocessing right?, then this will be a solution.
And I already coverted successfully with Pytorch(1,3,h,w) -> ONNX(1, 3, h, w) -> TF&TFLite(1,h,w,3) in Input Image, so I think this will be not a problem.

Comment: @Farmaker, I followed the link and tried your solution and got the same result as Android results. On PC, the model conversion is successful because the converted model shows the same value as before, but it's a bit confusing only on android.

Comment: Can you point at your code the ONNX(1, 3, h, w) -> TF&TFLite(1,h,w,3) conversion? and a link to take a look at your tflite file?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Yes, I see the tflite file and it seems ok. Since I cannot debug your project and I can make only suggestions, you can try to do the inference with the python API and your tflite model before you jump into android. There you can see how you can preprocess your input and if something is wrong. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python

Comment: @Farmaker that is the point. On PC with python API, It goes well. But on Android, it seems weird with output values. I don't understand why this is the only model that does this when other models don't.

Comment: Place here the python code that you do the inference with the Interpreter of TensorFlow Lite and the preprocessing of the image.

Comment: @Farmaker Sorry for very late comment, finally my model is not supported with gpuDelegate, so I changed it to nnapiDelegate. it solved my problem. Thank you for your comments.